# Toggle list using sub class

Tags: jquery, toggle

Toggle is not working with sub class (`.open`), it works with main tag (`li`).

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

Anything am I missing?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elyor/81ah4z1j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81ah4z1j/1/)**

The jQuery method **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** get the immediately following sibling.

**Problem :** You `.open` element doesn't have an `ul` sibling.

**Suggested solution :** Go up to the parent `li` then use the `.next()` that will target the `ul` sibling like :

```
$(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
//Or
$(this).parents('li').next('ul').toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> 11111111 <i class="open">open</i></li>
  <ul>
    <li> 1.1 </li>
    <li> 1.2 </li>
  </ul>
  <li> 22222222222 <i class="open">open</i></li>
  <ul>
    <li> 2.1 </li>
    <li> 2.2 </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()` for get the neareast closest element li `.next()` for select immediate ul element in the dom

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').next('ul').toggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/81ah4z1j/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent `li` element for the `.open` and then get the next `li` element for that partent item.

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').next('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put `$(this).next('ul').toggle();`it targets to the next ul inside the `<li>` where the .open object is located, but there is no `<ul>` there.

For that, you should use target the parent `<li>` and then target the next `<ul>` that follows it.

The code should be something like this:

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
});
```